# Give Apache Permission to Serve Files Outside of /var/www

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, permissions

I have my apache server and its specific files in /var/www and I have a bunch of group documents that I want to serve out in another directory /company/shared_files.  I wrote and alias and it seems like it worked but apache doesn't have permission to read it. What do I need to change because I have global read and execute permission for the /company/shared_files directory.

Here is the alias I have:

```
Alias /shared_files/ "/company/shared_files"
<Directory "/company/shared_files/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

I'm running the newest version of debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not you add allow directive to new  entry:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

Because root directory by default have "deny from all".

Comment: I also had to put a trailing / on the initial alias and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following might help:

- Add `Require all granted` inside `<Directory "/company/shared_files/"> ... </Directory>`.
- Make sure that the Apache user (apache on RedHat, www-data on Debian/Ubuntu) has read and execute permission on /company/shared_files and all of its parent directories, i.e. / and /company, and read permission on files within /company/shared_files.

See the [Require directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).

Comment: My mistake I was actually using 2.2 so Require all granted isn't yet allowed